# Add two hours to a date within given hours that rollover to the next timeframe

Tags: php, strtotime

How would I structure the conditions to add two hours only to dates between 08:30 in the morning until 18:30 of the evening, excluding Saturday and Sunday?

In the case that a time near the border (e.g. 17:30 on Tuesday) is given, the left over time should be added to the beginning of the next "valid" time period.

For example: if the given date was in 17:30 on Tuesday, the two hour addition would result in 9:30 on Wednesday (17:30 + 1 hour = 18:30, 8:30 + the remainder 1 hour = 9:30).  Or if the given date was in 17:00 on Friday, the result would be 9:00 on Monday (17:00 Friday + 1.5 hours = 18:30, 8:30 Monday + the remainder .5 hours = 9:00)

I know how to simply add two hours, as follows:

```
$idate1 = strtotime($_POST['date']);
$time1 = date('Y-m-d G:i', strtotime('+120 minutes', $idate1));
$_POST['due_date']  = $time1;
```

But what would I add to accomplish the above?

Comment: `17:30 (of Tuesday ) + 2 = 09:30` ?????

Comment: @relentless ( of Wednesday-the next day)

Comment: `if(date('is',$idate1)>830 && date('is',$idate1)<1830){...put here +120 minutes.....}` I think (may be I'm wrong)

Comment: I've submitted an edit to make your question clearer that should show once it's peer-reviewed - it was confusing what you're asking, hopefully I've made it plainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "magic numbers" and doing a lot of math with dates makes your code less readable, and also can cause problems - it doesn't deal well with leapyears, daylight savings time, time zones, or all the other weirdness that comes with dates and time.

When possible, you should *always* use helper functions like strtotime() to deal with dates and avoid doing math directly.

Here's my shot at doing what you want, it's not perfect (you can't add a time period larger than the gap between two periods - that is, 14 hours from 18:30 to 8:30 - and it still uses some raw math, but it's an improvement:

```
<?php
    function addRollover($givenDate, $addtime) {
        $starttime = 8.5*60; //Start time in minutes (decimal hours * 60)
        $endtime = 18.5*60; //End time in minutes (decimal hours * 60)

        $givenDate = strtotime($givenDate);

        //Get just the day portion of the given time
        $givenDay = strtotime('today', $givenDate);
        //Calculate what the end of today's period is
        $maxToday = strtotime("+$endtime minutes", $givenDay);
        //Calculate the start of the next period
        $nextPeriod = strtotime("tomorrow", $givenDay); //Set it to the next day
        $nextPeriod = strtotime("+$starttime minutes", $nextPeriod);  //And add the starting time
        //If it's the weekend, bump it to Monday
        if(date("D", $nextPeriod) == "Sat") {
            $nextPeriod = strtotime("+2 days", $nextPeriod);
        }

        //Add the time period to the new day
        $newDate = strtotime("+$addtime", $givenDate);
        //print "$givenDate -> $newDate\n";
        //print "$maxToday\n";
        //Get the new hour as a decimal (adding minutes/60)
        $hourfrac = date('H',$newDate) + date('i',$newDate)/60;
        //print "$hourfrac\n";

        //Check if we're outside the range needed
        if($hourfrac < $starttime || $hourfrac > $endtime) {
            //We're outside the range, find the remainder and add it on
            $remainder = $newDate - $maxToday;
            //print "$remainder\n";
            $newDate = $nextPeriod + $remainder;
        }

        return $newDate;
    }
?>
```

I've commented out the print statements I had for debugging, you can uncomment them if you want to see how it works (which I recommend!)
You use it as such:

```
<?php
    print date('Y-m-d H:i:s',addRollover('2013-01-01 17:30','2 hours')) . "\n";
    print date('Y-m-d H:i:s',addRollover('2013-01-01 18:00','3 hours')) . "\n";
    print date('Y-m-d H:i:s',addRollover('2013-01-04 17:00','150 minutes')) . "\n";
?>
```

Results in:

```
2013-01-02 09:30:00
2013-01-02 11:00:00
2013-01-07 09:30:00
```

This code should deal just fine with most weirdnesses of dates, such as timezones, daylight savings, and such.  It would be even better implemented with PHP's [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), but that is fairly new and I'm not as familiar with it, so I stuck with strtotime().

Comment: tested and it works, this is exactly what i wanted, tnk you so much for your help

Comment: there is a problem with your function, when i use a date like ( 2013-11-26 12:30 )  he gives me ( 2013-11-27 04:30:00  )

Comment: here you can find it as question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229093/php-add-two-hours-to-a-date-within-given-hours-using-function

Comment: Sounds like it's time for some debugging.  If you uncomment the `print` statements, maybe wrapping them in a date() function so they're more readable, can you find where things are going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The date function works with UNIX timestamps, therefore I just add 86400 (seconds in a day), then divide it by 24 and multiply by 2. That's exactly 2 hours more.

```
$time1 = date('Y-m-d G:i', strtotime($idate1)+86400/12);
```

If you'd like to only apply these changes in a certain period, you can use ( timestamp modulo 86400 ) formula to get the hours and minutes.

```
if(($idate%86400)>=(86400/24*8.5)&&($idate%86400)<=(86400/24*18.5)) 
$time1 = date('Y-m-d G:i', strtotime($idate1)+86400/12);
```

For filtering the weekends, `date()` will help you:

```
if(date("D",$idate)=="Sun" || date("D",$idate)=="Sat)
```

Now merge the conditions, and we get the solution for the first part:

```
if(date("D",$idate)!="Sun" && date("D",$idate)!="Sat" && ($idate%86400)>=(86400/24*8.5)&&($idate%86400)<=(86400/24*18.5)) 
$time1 = date('Y-m-d G:i', strtotime($idate1)+86400/12);
```

> *Note: You must use UTC+0 timezone in the script for this to work.*

Comment: tnk  you fr the answer 
(( 86400/12 )) May i know what does it mean ?

Comment: many tnks fr the effort, in order to test your code in the real life does it respect the period above ?

Comment: where can i see if i'm using (UTC+0 timezone ) ?

Comment: just set it with `date_default_timezone_set()` function

Comment: There are a lot of "magic numbers" here, the strtotime() function was created for a reason.  All the constants and math make it very difficult to read, and introduce timezone dependencies.

Comment: so i have to put `date_default_timezone_set();` in the php page that contain my code ?

Comment: I agree, if you can, use `strtotime()`, I'm used to this somehow.

Comment: @user1233875 Not exactly, you also add 'UTC' as the argument.