# PHP Add two hours to a date within given hours using function

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-math

How would I structure the conditions to add two hours only to dates between 08:30 in the morning until 18:30 of the evening, excluding Saturday and Sunday?

In the case that a time near the border (e.g. 17:30 on Tuesday) is given, the left over time should be added to the beginning of the next "valid" time period.

For example: if the given date was in 17:30 on Tuesday, the two hour addition would result in 9:30 on Wednesday (17:30 + 1 hour = 18:30, 8:30 + the remainder 1 hour = 9:30). Or if the given date was in 17:00 on Friday, the result would be 9:00 on Monday (17:00 Friday + 1.5 hours = 18:30, 8:30 Monday + the remainder .5 hours = 9:00)

I know how to simply add two hours, as follows:

```
$idate1 = strtotime($_POST['date']);
$time1 = date('Y-m-d G:i', strtotime('+120 minutes', $idate1));
$_POST['due_date']  = $time1;
```

i have tried this this function and it works great except when i use a date like ( 2013-11-26 12:30 ) he gives me ( 2013-11-27 04:30:00 ) 
the problem is with 12:30

```
function addRollover($givenDate, $addtime) {
    $starttime = 8.5*60; //Start time in minutes (decimal hours * 60)
    $endtime = 18.5*60; //End time in minutes (decimal hours * 60)

    $givenDate = strtotime($givenDate);

    //Get just the day portion of the given time
    $givenDay = strtotime('today', $givenDate);
    //Calculate what the end of today's period is
    $maxToday = strtotime("+$endtime minutes", $givenDay);
    //Calculate the start of the next period
    $nextPeriod = strtotime("tomorrow", $givenDay); //Set it to the next day
    $nextPeriod = strtotime("+$starttime minutes", $nextPeriod);  //And add the starting time
    //If it's the weekend, bump it to Monday
    if(date("D", $nextPeriod) == "Sat") {
        $nextPeriod = strtotime("+2 days", $nextPeriod);
    }

    //Add the time period to the new day
    $newDate = strtotime("+$addtime", $givenDate);
    //print "$givenDate -> $newDate\n";
    //print "$maxToday\n";
    //Get the new hour as a decimal (adding minutes/60)
    $hourfrac = date('H',$newDate) + date('i',$newDate)/60;
    //print "$hourfrac\n";

    //Check if we're outside the range needed
    if($hourfrac < $starttime || $hourfrac > $endtime) {
        //We're outside the range, find the remainder and add it on
        $remainder = $newDate - $maxToday;
        //print "$remainder\n";
        $newDate = $nextPeriod + $remainder;
    }

    return $newDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need this but here it is anyway. **Requires PHP 5.3 or higher**

```
<?php
function addRollover($givenDate, $addtime) {
    $datetime = new DateTime($givenDate);
    $datetime->modify($addtime);

    if (in_array($datetime->format('l'), array('Sunday','Saturday')) || 
        17 < $datetime->format('G') || 
        (17 === $datetime->format('G') && 30 < $datetime->format('G'))
    ) {
        $endofday = clone $datetime;
        $endofday->setTime(17,30);
        $interval = $datetime->diff($endofday);

        $datetime->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
        if (in_array($datetime->format('l'), array('Saturday', 'Sunday'))) {
            $datetime->modify('next Monday');
        }
        $datetime->setTime(8,30);
        $datetime->add($interval);
    }

    return $datetime;
}

$future = addRollover('2014-01-03 15:15:00', '+4 hours');
echo $future->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[**See it in action**](http://3v4l.org/Ac8ro)

Here's an explanation of what's going on:

1. First we create a DateTime object representing our starting date/time
2. We then add the specified amount of time to it (see [Supported Date and Time Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php))
3. We check to see if it is a weekend, after 6PM, or in the 5PM hour with more than 30 minutes passed (e.g. after 5:30PM)
4. If so we clone our datetime object and set it to 5:30PM
5. We then get the difference between the end time (5:30PM) and the modified time as a [DateInterval object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)
6. We then progress to the next day
7. If the next day is a Saturday we progress to the next day
8. If the next day is a Sunday we progress to the next day
9. We then set our time to 8:30AM
10. We then add our difference between the end time (5:30PM) and the modified time to our datetime object
11. We return the object from the function

Comment: Thanks this is a great function but it is returning back on a sunday.

Comment: I added $future = addRollover('2014-06-26 11:41:00', '+63 hours');
echo $future->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); and it returned 2014-06-29 17:41:00 which is a sunday.

Comment: I thought you had forgotten about this question! I confirmed your test and the fix was easy. I just had to change `$endofday->diff($datetime);` to `$datetime->diff($endofday);`. The previous result was negative which subtracted the time we were trying to add.

Comment: Im not the original poster of the question but I need something very similar, check out my post here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427553/datetime-class-create-a-function-to-add-hours-onto-a-deadline-taking-into-accoun

Comment: Also it is still not correct if I put this input in :2014-06-26 15:17:00', '+36 hours' it returns 2014-06-30 22:43:00 but 22:43 is outside the working hours of 08:30 to 17:30. Surly it should roll over to next day again?